# Equivalent to "call" command

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, vba

I'm sure this is a dumb question, but I can't find the answer anywhere. In Apps Script, is there an equivalent to the VBA "Call" command? I want to call one Function from within another Function, by the name as a string.

```
function ClearFields(){
calc.getRange('A3:C15').clearContent()
"Call" function example1
}
```

Comment: You just call it like this `example1()`. Using `call` to call a function is just a quirk only VBA has. And would not even be required in your case if it was VBA. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/call-statement

Comment: Thanks, I knew it had to be something simple.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function example1(){
calc.getRange('G3:G15').clearContent()

}


function ClearFields(){
calc.getRange('A3:C15').clearContent()
example1(); // This will execute the function
}
```